# I want to change query to URL Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the URL mywebsite.com/cauta?city=selectedCity to mywebsite.com/cauta-in-selectedCity.

Here is my browse() in controller

AdController.php

```
public function browse()
    {
        $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? Input::get('min_price') : 0;
        $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? Input::get('max_price') : 1000;

        $air_conditioning = Input::has('air_conditioning') ? Input::get('air_conditioning') : null;
        $parking = Input::has('parking') ? Input::get('parking') : null;
        $terace = Input::has('terace') ? Input::get('terace') : null;
        $garden = Input::has('garden') ? Input::get('garden') : null;
        $elevator = Input::has('elevator') ? Input::get('elevator') : null;
        $clothes_machine = Input::has('clothes_machine') ? Input::get('clothes_machine') : null;
        $dishes_machine = Input::has('dishes_machine') ? Input::get('dishes_machine') : null;
        $cable_internet = Input::has('cable_internet') ? Input::get('cable_internet') : null;
        $wifi_internet = Input::has('wifi_internet') ? Input::get('wifi_internet') : null;
        $tv = Input::has('TV') ? Input::get('TV') : null;
        $microwaves = Input::has('microwaves') ? Input::get('microwaves') : null;
        $fridge = Input::has('fridge') ? Input::get('fridge') : null;
        $own_heat = Input::has('own_heat') ? Input::get('own_heat') : null;
        $build_heat = Input::has('build_heat') ? Input::get('build_heat') : null;
        $number_of_rooms = Input::has('number_of_rooms') ? Input::get('number_of_rooms') : null;
        $city = Input::has('city') ? Input::get('city') : null;
        $AcceptsPets = Input::has('AcceptsPets') ? Input::get('AcceptsPets') : null;

        $order = Input::has('order') ? Input::get('order') : 'asc';
        $orderBy='id';

        if($order == 'asc') {

            $orderBy = 'rent';

          }

          if($order == 'descs'){
            $order = 'desc';
            $orderBy = 'rent';
          }

          if($order == 'new'){
            $order = 'desc';
            $orderBy = 'id';

          }



        $ads = Ad::where(function($query) use($min_price, $max_price, $air_conditioning, $parking,
                $terace, $garden, $elevator, $clothes_machine, $dishes_machine, $cable_internet,
                $wifi_internet, $tv, $microwaves, $fridge, $own_heat, $build_heat,
                $number_of_rooms,$city,$AcceptsPets, $order){
            if(!is_null($min_price) && !is_null($max_price)){

              if(!is_null($air_conditioning)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('air_conditioning', '=', $air_conditioning);
              }

              if(!is_null($parking)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('parking', '=', $parking);
              }

              if(!is_null($terace)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('terace', '=', $terace);
              }

              if(!is_null($garden)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('garden', '=', $garden);
              }

              if(!is_null($elevator)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('elevator', '=', $elevator);
              }

              if(!is_null($clothes_machine)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('clothes_machine', '=', $clothes_machine);
              }

              if(!is_null($dishes_machine)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('dishes_machine', '=', $dishes_machine);
              }

              if(!is_null($cable_internet)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('cable_internet', '=', $cable_internet);
              }

              if(!is_null($wifi_internet)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('wifi_internet', '=', $wifi_internet);
              }

              if(!is_null($tv)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('TV', '=', $tv);
              }

              if(!is_null($microwaves)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('microwaves', '=', $microwaves);
              }

              if(!is_null($fridge)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('fridge', '=', $fridge);
              }

              if(!is_null($own_heat)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('own_heat', '=', $own_heat);
              }

              if(!is_null($build_heat)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('build_heat', '=', $build_heat);
              }

              if(!is_null($number_of_rooms)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('number_of_rooms', '=', $number_of_rooms);
              }

              if(!is_null($city)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('city', '=', $city);
              }

              if(!is_null($AcceptsPets)){
                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price)
                ->where('AcceptsPets', '=', $AcceptsPets);
              }

                $query-> where('rent', '>=', $min_price)
                ->where('rent','<=',$max_price);

            }


        })->where('available', '=', 'Accept')->orderBy($orderBy,$order)->paginate(9);

        $number = count($ads);

        return view('browse', compact('ads', 'min_price', 'max_price', 'air_conditioning',
                                      'parking', 'terace', 'garden', 'elevator',
                                      'clothes_machine','dishes_machine', 'cable_internet',
                                      'wifi_internet', 'tv', 'microwaves', 'fridge',
                                      'own_heat', 'build_heat', 'number_of_rooms',
                                      'city', 'number', 'AcceptsPets', 'order'
                                    ));
    }
```

My route

web.php

```
Route::get('/cauta', 'AdController@browse');
```

The form where I make the search

```
<form action="/cauta">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-8 pr-0">
      <div class="input-group text-left">
        <select class="custom-select custom-search-city" name="city" data-toggle="select">
          <option value="" selected>Toate orașele</option>
          <option value="Alba Iulia">Alba Iulia</option>
          <option value="Arad">Arad</option>
          <option value="Bacau">Bacău</option>
          <option value="Baia Mare">Baia Mare</option>
          <option value="Bistrita">Bistrița</option>
          <option value="Blaj">Blaj</option>
          <option value="Brasov">Brașov</option>
          <option value="Bucuresti">București</option>
          <option value="Cernica">Cernica</option>
          <option value="Cluj-Napoca">Cluj-Napoca</option>
          <option value="Constanta">Constanța</option>
          <option value="Craiova">Craiova</option>
          <option value="Deva">Deva</option>
          <option value="Galati">Galați</option>
          <option value="Iasi">Iași</option>
          <option value="Lugoj">Lugoj</option>
          <option value="Oradea">Oradea</option>
          <option value="Piatra Neamt">Piatra Neamț</option>
          <option value="Pitesti">Pitești</option>
          <option value="Ploiesti">Ploiești</option>
          <option value="Roman">Roman</option>
          <option value="Satu Mare">Satu Mare</option>
          <option value="Sibiu">Sibiu</option>
          <option value="Suceava">Suceava</option>
          <option value="Targu Jiu">Târgu Jiu</option>
          <option value="Targu Mures">Târgu Mureș</option>
          <option value="Timisoara">Timișoara</option>
          <option value="Alte orase">Alte orașe</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-4 pl-0 text-left pl-1">
      <button class="btn btn-info">
        <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Search</span>
        <span class="ml-md-2 fa fa-search"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would like, when I click the search button, to get a URL like /cauta-in-selectedCity.

I tried with a 301 redirect but it is not working.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this result?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your redirect attempt? What didn't work?

Comment: @Jerodev I tried this but is not redirecting: Route::get('cauta?city=Alba+Iulia', function(){
    return Redirect::to('/cauta-in-Alba-Iulia', 301);
});

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using adding an optional parameter to your route. [See documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-optional-parameters).

Change web.php to:

`Route::get('/cauta-in-{city?}', 'AdController@browse');`

And then in AdController.php:

`public function browse($city) {
     // $city will have the value of the city the user just selected
}`

Comment: Thank you for your answear. I modified this and now I added   <form action="{{ action('AdController@browse') }}"> and it gives me the following link: cauta-in-?city=selectedCity. Any idea in how can I pass it to the form so it will give me 'cauta-in-selectedCity? Thank you

Comment: You get the query ?city=selectedCity because the route is GET. You can make another route in this case. If your initial route is used just for processing the form, you can change it to be POST and upon filtering the results, redirect to the city-in-{city?} route.